# Equation of a plane passing through intersection of two planes and parallel to a given line.

Tags: 3d, plane-geometry

The equation of plane passing through the intersection of planes $x+y-z=2$ and $2x-y+3z=5$ and parallel to the line $p=i+a (2i-j)$ is?

---

$\text {Attempt }$: We know the equation of such plane is $r_1+b(r_2)=n_1+b (n_2) $ where $r_1,r_2$ are planes and $n_1,n_2$ are constants. Also it is given that its parallel to a line with direction ratios $2,-1,0$ thus the direction ratios of its normal are $1,2,0$ . So this satisfies the equation of third plane which passes through intersection of two planes . So I put values to get $b=1/5$ but I am not getting the right answer  as my solution and answer keys' solution is not matching . Where is my fault in understanding the question? Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be a "minus" sign. Please check my edit.

Comment: Where? I see everything correct

Comment: You wrote the first equation as $x+y_z=3$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Ask first, Edit next

Comment: Ya its right. Thanks!